# How can I pause my threaded game in java, Using a toggle method from key input?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have the main game while loop under the condition `running`, so when `running` is false the game stops running, this is threaded.

Here is the method for when I press the *P* key on keyboard to pause the game, I've tried a few things and nothing seems to work, my goal is to make it so that when I press *P* the game is paused (which it does) thereafter I can press *P* again to unpause.

```
    boolean pause = false;
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        pause = true;
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
           if (key == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
                 if(pause) {
                 running = false;

                 } else {
                 running = true;
                 pause = false;
                 }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `pause = true` as the first line of keyPressed, pressing <kbd>P</kbd> will always pause the game. Try this instead:

```
boolean pause = false;
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P) {
        pause = !pause;
        running = !pause;
    }
}
```